# My emails to mailing list go missing in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, mailing-lists

Thunderbird 91.9.1

When I send an email to mailing list such as gnucash-user or other similar mailing lists, my submissions go missing. This happens at both times when I start a new thread or respond to a thread started by someone else.

My mail is received and distributed properly by the mailing list. I can also see the responses to my email, only my email is missing. This often causes context loss if the responding party does not include my fully email in the reply.

How do I convince Thunderbird to show my emails also

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't show email to **each** recipient in the list? That's because sending mail CC: only puts a single copy on the server. If you send BCC:, then each recipient receives a separate email from the server.

Comment: No, the mailing list etiquette is to reply to only list. All the mails are replied to list. If I start the thread, my view of thunderbird does not show my email. However I can see the responses